# How to modify a 2D array from multiple threads without synchronization

Tags: java, data-structures

How to design a 2D array in java in such a way that it allows multiple threads to modify or insert value at a particular position without using synchronization

Comment: is it possible or it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Well you cannot do it without synchronization. Only thing you can do is reduce the scope of he lock used. If you don't know yet, read about lock coarsening. ConcurrentHashMap uses it. Idea is that instead of locking the whole array to modifications you just lock a segment of array (e.g: start, middle or end) where the modification would happen. This keeps the array DS open for reads and writes by other threads and no blocking happens unless 2 threads try to mutate the same segment simultaneously.

Comment: Agree ... Looks like a question to see how a candidate will react facing a badly asked problem ...

Comment: Yeah true. Seems to me like a quick lab based question.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do it.

Firstly, if you want maximum concurrency as a common library regardless of how many threads are accessing the matrix, and your `int[][]` is reasonably small, you can do like this.

1. Set up a matrix of `AtomicBoolean` equals to the dimension of the `int[][]`.
2. While you are trying to update the int matrix, lock that `AtomicBoolean` first, the use `Unsafe.putIntVolatile()` to update the value in volatile way, then unluck the `AtomicBoolean`.

Secondly, if you know the number of threads in advance.

1. Keep a marker object/value as per thread like int; then create an additional int[][] as the marker matrix. Initialize the marker matrix to some dummy value which doesn't equal to any of your thread marker value, e.g. -1.
2. While you are trying to update the int matrix, lock the cell in thr marker matrix by using `Unsafe.compareAndSet()` first; then update it by `Unsafe.putIntVolatile()`; and finally unmark the marker matrix by reset the value to -1.

Lastly, if you can tolerate the `int[][]` isn't really an int matrix in the actual code, what you can do is to use a `long[][]` matrix, where the first 32 bit is the current number of updates to the value and the last 32 bit is the current value. Then you can easily use `Unsafe.compareAndSet()` to set this long value as a whole. Note you can circular the upper 32 bit value so you don't have to have a update upper limit == `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1):

Does this question make sense? If we assume an `int[][]` all operations on it will be atomic so there should be no need for synchronization! But what confuses me on the question: you cannot insert values in means of changing the array bounds after you have declared it.

Comment: Given some array `a[][]`, even a simple operation like `a[i][j]++` is *not* atomic .

Comment: Assignment would be atomic but you would not have any visibility guarantee so it would not be thread safe without synchronisation.

Comment: Hmm well, then the Array should be of type `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger`.

Comment: Atomic Integer could be the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that each *element* of the array(s) is only ever accessed by a single thread (until you completed the computation that can change the array(s) contents), then you can safely use many threads. (because they will be effectively independent) Otherwise, it's probably a bad idea…

Answer (score 0):

Create a `static` variable that can be accessed by all your `Thread`s like:

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Constants.intValue[0][0] = new Integer(10);
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Constants.intValue[0][1] = new Integer(20);
            }
        });

        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (Integer[] valueArr : Constants.intValue) {
                    for (Integer intValue : valueArr) {
                        System.err.println(intValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

    }

}

interface Constants {

    Integer[][] intValue = new Integer[2][2];

}
```

The only case will be next thread will override previous set value if it is using the same array position.

Comment: If you do read / write a thousand times, will you always get the *updated* value here?. I don't think so.

Comment: @SameerSawla its simple, the static variable will be accessible to all the Thread, and it will solve the above question.

Comment: using static variable this way is not an intended use of them. And do try to run your code with a loop of 100 to 200 threads each changing and reading from 5 to 6 cell positions. You would see it doesn't do what it should.